# Responsive centered image slider

Tags: responsive-design

I tried to implement a touchslider in my website. However, I didn't success to have a responsive image inside my slider container.
I need that the images get full size of the container. The size of the image and slider container need to be responsive when the web browser is resized.

Currently, my images are bigger than the slider container and are not resized when the browser is resized.

Here you can find my problem example : http://fiddle.jshell.net/WLRYW/

My website : http://freakyshape.com/#/portfolio/dock.html

Sorry for my english, I'm french...

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code. Just give the specific width to the parent element in percentages(% ex- 70%), not in pixels. If an element's parent will be scalable by percentages, child'll be automatically try to be responsive. Don't try `width:auto;` Browser assume its width to 0. You can use `height:auto;` but not width. So use min-height for images in slider and maintain their size with `height: auto;` and `width: 90%;` (for-example). I haven't got your website url otherwise i could tell you more specifically.

Comment: Thank you for the answere. I really tried but without success. I don't understand how to adapt the image size to the container. How to stretch it...Here a simplified example : http://fiddle.jshell.net/Khg7Z/

Comment: Replace <div style="width:10000px"> with <div style="width:100%"> and you have written semantically wrong this .touchslider-image img{} in your CSS so change it to img.touchslider-image{}. Only some changes'll make it responsive. If possible define each element's width separately either you've used max-width or not but in % not in pixels. Because we make browser to be confused defining max-width but not telling what its exactly width is currently. Put the changes i've mentioned above. Hope this'll help you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't seen before that I have some style in my html code... I tried your advices, however if I don't set an element in pixel, the slider become very narrow. I miss something... Here the fiddle updated : http://fiddle.jshell.net/Khg7Z/1/

Comment: use min-width where you want it to be set ant not to be stretched further.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I tried with min-width, width, height, min-height ... in %, in px, with auto, but it still don't work.